# Sonatype-Nexus-OSS- LDAP support

Tags: nexus

The documentation says LDAP supports 4 different types of authentication in Nexus 
a.  Simple , b. Anonymous, c.   DIGEST-MD5 ,d.  CRAM MD-5

1) I used LDAP simple authentication after which it was not able to authenticate me using my active directory password

2) After enabling LDAP simple authentication, clicking on logout has no effect

3) Anonymous access is still required even after enabling LDAP simple authentication

4) To send encrypted passwords over network do I HAVE TO buy Nexus Pro?

5) When I use DIGEST-MD5 or CRAMMD5 authentication, and test it, I get a bad request error.

Can someone please help me with the answers?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Our nexus is setup to do user authentication against an active directory.  It was setup using the doc here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/ldap.html

To answer your questions:

1) for your username, are you using a full path to your user?  Example: CN=Users,OU=Organization,DC=mycompany,DC=com

2) Probably related to the failure caused by #1.  Logout works fine for me.

3) You can allow that under Administration -> Server.  There's a checkbox for anonymous access and you provide the user/password for the anonymous account.  Then you setup the permissions for that account to allow however much anonymous access you want/need.

4) If you consider ldaps (ldap over ssl) "encrypted" then no.  If not, I believe so.

5) I haven't tried those ever as we wanted authentication via AD.

Comment: 1) My search base is "cn=SVNSVC,ou=Services,ou=Accounts,dc=mycompany,dc=net";This is how it is set in my company's ssl.conf. Also when I click on "check authentication" it shows ldap connection and authentication tested sucessfully. After this step, I go back to administration ->server->security settings and turn security on. It asks for a username and password. I enter my AD username and password and it throws the username and password box again! 3) Why should anonymous access be allowed when I want users to authenticate using AD only 4) You mean if I use ldaps, my password will be encrypted?

Comment: 2 things to check if the authentication works when you hit "check authentication".  1) do you have the user id attribute set correctly?  2) if you log in as "admin", then go to security, users, and search for "LDAP" users using your username, do you find yourself?

Comment: My ldap config looks like this.  Protocol:ldap hostname:server.mycompany.com port:3268 searchbase:DC=mycompany,DC=com authentication-method:simple sasl-realm:<blank> username:CN=ad-username,OU=organization,DC=mycompany,DC=com password:ad-password.  check auth works for me then.  Then in the user element mapping section I have:  base-dn:<blank> user-subtree:checked object-class:user user-id-attr:sAMAccountName real-name:cn email:mail   Then when i go to security users, LDAP and search for myself, it shows up.  Pretty much directly followed the nexus book doc

Comment: Ok.. I will check this again. Do you know the answer for my other question on encryption? If I use ldap it means that my password is sent as clear text over network. I do not see any crypt option in OSS. Should I buy pro version if I want to use ldap for AD and encrypt password? Thanks

Comment: There's options for md5 so something should work if AD supports it.  I don't know, as we don't use it